# How can I copy a "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots" appsettings values into a file?

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Using an ARM template, I populate new and existing secrets from a keyvault (and a few environment specific settings) into the appsettings for a staging slot.

As part of the release pipeline I overwrite some of the appsettings on a slot with test values using the `az webapp config appsettings set` command.

After this, I need to revert the appsettings back to the original values from the ARM template prior to swapping my slot with the production slot.

Can I directly copy the slot's appsettings to a file in the pipeline, or create an additional file in the ARM template?
This would allow me to reapply the production settings after I run my tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I directly copy the slot's appsettings to a file in the pipeline, or create an additional file in the ARM template?

Of course， you can achieve it.

You could try to use the following command to output the appsettings to the Json file.

```
$result=az webapp config appsettings list --name WebAppName -g  ResourceGroupName --slot slotname  

$result | Out-File "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\file.json"
```

Then the appsettings will be output to the json file.

For example:

[image]

After running the test, you could run the following command to  revert the appsettings back to the original values.

```
az webapp config appsettings set -g ResourceGroupName -n WebAppName  --slot slotname --settings  "@$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\file.json"
```

Here is the doc about [az web app config settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest).